# Use HTTPS and IMAP services on the same port

Tags: https, imap, multiplexing

Is there any multiplexer that allows the use of both HTTPS and IMAP on port 993 like what SSLH does for SSH and HTTPS & etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HAProxy in TCP mode, inspect `req.payload` for the appropriate protocol and then select a backend based on the result.